# Extend result with data that does not exist in this way

Tags: mysql

sorry but i can't say the words for my target.
maybe someone understand my problem with the example below:

stored data:

```
brand   warehouse   amount
-----------------------
ba      a           1
bb      a           1
ba      b           1
bb      c           1
```

i want to write a select query that get result like the following:

```
brand   warehouse   amount
-----------------------
ba      a           1
bb      a           1
ba      b           1
bb      b           null
ba      c           null
bb      c           1
```

brand "bb" is not in the warehouse "a" but exists in other warehouse, then the brand should be listed anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we want to generate a cross product of `brand` and `warehouse`.

Here's one way to do it:

Get a distinct list of `brand` values:

```
SELECT bt.brand 
  FROM stored_data bt
 GROUP BY bt.brand
```

Get a distinct list of `warehouse` values:

```
SELECT wt.warehouse
  FROM stored_data wt
 GROUP BY wt.warehouse
```

Generate a Cartesian product (cross product) of those two sets:

```
SELECT b.brand
     , w.warehouse
  FROM ( SELECT bt.brand
           FROM stored_data bt
          GROUP BY bt.brand
       ) b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT wt.warehouse
           FROM stored_data wt
          GROUP BY wt.warehouse
       ) w
 ORDER 
    BY b.brand
     , w.warehouse
```

---

The next step is an outer join to get the `amount` column.  If `(brand,warehouse)` tuple is unique in `stored_data`, then we can just do:

```
SELECT b.brand
     , w.warehouse
     , a.amount
  FROM ( SELECT bt.brand
           FROM stored_data bt
          GROUP BY bt.brand
       ) b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT wt.warehouse
           FROM stored_data wt
          GROUP BY wt.warehouse
       ) w
  LEFT
  JOIN stored_data a
    ON a.brand     = b.brand
   AND a.warehouse = w.warehouse
 ORDER 
    BY b.brand
     , w.warehouse
```

---

If `(brand,warehouse)` is not unique, then the query has the potential to return multiple rows with the same values of brand and warehouse.

If we want to collapse the rows and get a total `amount`, the normative pattern would be to use GROUP BY and an aggregate function:

```
SELECT b.brand
     , w.warehouse
     , SUM(a.amount) AS amount
  FROM ( SELECT bt.brand
           FROM stored_data bt
          GROUP BY bt.brand
       ) b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT wt.warehouse
           FROM stored_data wt
          GROUP BY wt.warehouse
       ) w
  LEFT
  JOIN stored_data a
    ON a.brand     = b.brand
   AND a.warehouse = w.warehouse
 GROUP
    BY b.brand
     , w.warehouse
 ORDER 
    BY b.brand
     , w.warehouse
```

There are other possible query patterns that will achieve and equivalent result.

Comment: "Get a distinct list of brand values:" I would have used `DISTINCT` there instead off `GROUP BY` same goes for the warehouses.. Using `GROUP BY` there is offcource not wrong but for some reason `DISTINCT` feels beter suited and more natural here to because also no aggregate functions are used there.. Still +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Warehouse table, make one using the stored_data

```
SELECT
    D.brand,
    W.warehouse
FROM
    (Select 
        DISTINCT warehouse
    FROM stored_data
    ) W LEFT JOIN stored_data D on W.warehouse = D.warehouse
ORDER By D.brand, D.warehouse
```